# Fail to split string at each instance of character in R

Tags: r, string

I am using R to try and separate a long string of numbers all separated by the ";" character. The string looks like this:

```
";0,38;0,33;0,24;0,28; 0,33;0,33;0,38;0,23; 0,33;0,33; 0,38; 0,43; 0,51;0,56;0,33;0,56;0,33;0,43;0,51;0,56;\n\n0,61; 0,66;0,56; 0,66;0,56; 0,61; 0,66;0,61; 0,63; 0,66; 0,71;0,81;0,86; 0,99;0,86; 0,99; 1,12;1,27; 1,54; 1,57"
```

I have tried to do

```
 strsplit(string,";")
```

and

```
 str(string,";")
```

What is the quick way to do this so that I end up with a list of all the numbers in my list? Is there a way to do this with tidy verse?

Comment: `library(stringr) ; str_split(x, ";")` should work

Comment: @OganM, what I tried did not work. I understand tidyverse is not another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scan function allow using semicolons as separators and commas as decimal points (at least for input).

```
> vals <- scan(text=string,  sep=";", dec=",")
Read 42 items
> vals
 [1]   NA 0.38 0.33 0.24 0.28 0.33 0.33 0.38 0.23 0.33 0.33 0.38 0.43 0.51 0.56 0.33 0.56 0.33
[19] 0.43 0.51 0.56   NA 0.61 0.66 0.56 0.66 0.56 0.61 0.66 0.61 0.63 0.66 0.71 0.81 0.86 0.99
[37] 0.86 0.99 1.12 1.27 1.54 1.57
```

Comment: Thank you! Additionally, thank you for helping convert the comma's to decimals! I would've had to do that next.

Comment: It's a European convention. The read.delim function also handles it.